Optimizing numerical quadrature and order of accuracary
I am trying to solve a multi-part question from a past examination related to numerical analysis so that I can prepare for a future examination.
We consider the following quadrature
$$\int_0^h f(x)\,dx=af(0)+bf(c)$$
and for $c=h$, I am asked to the find optimal $a,b$ such that the formula is valid for the highest degree polynomial possible, and to find this degree. Naturally, I employ Lagrange interpolation and compute $\int_0^h \Pi_1(x)\,dx=\int_0^h \frac{h-x}{h}f(0)+\frac{x}{h}f(h)\,dx=\frac{h}{2}f(0)+ \frac{h}{2}f(h)$ so $a=b=h/2$ and since we have the error formula $f(x)-\Pi_1(x)= f''(\xi(x))x(x-h)$, $\xi(x)\in[0,h]$ the highest degree polynomial for which this quadrature is exact 1 since then $f''(\xi)\equiv 0$.
Next, instead of letting $c=h$, I would like to determine $c$ such that the error of the quadrature is minimized and the resulting order of accuracy. In this case, $\Pi_1(x,c)=\frac{c-x}{c}f(0)+\frac{x}{c}f(c)$. I thus find that
$$\int_0^h f(x)-\Pi_1(x,c)\,dx = \int_0^h \left(\frac{c-x}{c}\right)(f(x)-f(0))+ \frac{x}{c}(f(x)-f(c))\,dx \\
 =\int_0^h \left(\frac{c-x}{c}\right)\left(xf'(0)+ \frac{1}{2}x^2 f''(\xi(x))\right)\,dx + \int_0^h \frac{x}{c} \left(f'(c)(x-c)+\frac{1}{2} f''(\eta(x)) (x-c)^2\right).$$
At this point, is is clear that for $h$ small, we should choose $c$ such that $\int_0^h (c-x)x\,dx=0$ to cancel out the two largest terms in the above expression at once. This implies that $c=2h/3$. The error is then bounded by
$$\left|\int_0^h f(x)-\Pi_1(x,c)\,dx\right| \le C\| f''\|_{L^\infty([0,h])} \,h^3.$$
Does this imply that the order of accuracy is then 3? Note I am also unsure of the definition of the order of accuracy, and I am assuming it is the largest exponent $n$ such that the error is bounded above by $C\,h^n$. Please correct me if I have the wrong definition.
The last question I seek to answer is to find the highest order of accuracy if $f$ has a discontinuity in the interval $[0,h]$. To do so, I defined the following discontinuous function
$$f=0\cdot 1_{\{0\cup h\}} + 1_{\{0<x<h\}}.$$
The above Lagrange interpolation with $c=h$ gives the quadrature $(h/2)\cdot 0 + (h/2)\cdot 0=0$. However, the integral of $f$ is 1. Thus, the error is $\ge C h^0$. On the other hand, we always have that the error is bounded above by $\int_0^h |f|+ \Pi_1(x)\,dx\le C'h^0$ since we can take $0<h<1$. Thus, the highest order of accuracy is $0$, and in fact cannot be any lower.
I would like feedback on my bold questions and the correctness of my calculations.

And you might have a look at Radau quadrature if later you allow flexibility with $c$.

In terms of Newton's divided differences, the error term is
$$
\int_0^hf[0,c,c,x]\,x(x-c)^2\,dx=f[0,c,c,\zeta(h)]\int_0^hx(x-c)^2\,dx\sim f'''(\xi(h))\,h^4
$$
This means that the method is of order 3 for functions that are thrice continuously differentiable.

Can you add more details as to you get the the left most term as the error? In particular, I seem to still be getting terms of order $f''(\xi(h)) h^3$ in the error.

But you selected $c$ so that the integration of $f(x)=x(x-c)$ is exact. This then extends to all quadratic polynomials and thus to the quadratic Taylor polynomial. The remainder term is then of third order/degree, integrating to something $\sim f'''(\xi)h^4$. For the full Newton polynomial and coefficients see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4948301/115115, one would have to scale the unit interval to the interval $[0,h]$ to get an explicit error order.
